# clicking save button data not inserted into database in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hi In My Application I am Displaying Student name and roll no and check box with name present.Now student names and roll no coming from database Now if I click save button I want to insert all the records in another table. If I click Save Button I want Save all the data Into database.Now,If I click Save Button it giving unfortunately error.

Can Any one please help me.

**Attend.java**

```
public class Attend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView studentName;
    EditText studentname,rollno;
    CheckBox present;
    String[] class_name, section_name;
    String[] words;
    String name;
    String roll;
    Button save;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

         save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save); 

         save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //save.setText("Record Saved Sucessfully");
                name = studentname.getText().toString();
                roll =rollno.getText().toString();
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save","");
            }


        });

        String class_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("class_id");
        String section_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_id");
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Result : " + "\nclassName : " + class_id + "\nSectionName : "
                        + section_id,

                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String queryString = "class_id=" + class_id + "&section_id="
                + section_id;
        /*String result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",
                queryString);*/

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();

    }

    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StudentDetails user = new StudentDetails();
                // user.setId(json_data.getInt("class_name"));
                // user.setClass_id(json_data.getInt("section_name"));
                // user.setSection_id(json_data.getInt("section_id"));
                user.setStudentname(json_data.getString("first_name"));
                user.setRollno(json_data.getString("roll_no"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader() {

        tr = new TableRow(this);

        studentName = new TextView(this);


        studentName.setText("StudentName");

        studentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        studentName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        studentName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(studentName, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        TextView rollNumber = new TextView(this);
        rollNumber.setText("RollNo");
        rollNumber.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rollNumber.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        rollNumber.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(rollNumber, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);
        TextView Present = new TextView(this);
        Present.setText("Present");
        Present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Present.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(Present, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<StudentDetails> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            StudentDetails p = (StudentDetails) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            studentName = new EditText(this);
            studentName.setText(p.getStudentname());
            studentName.setId(p.getId());
            studentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            studentName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(studentName, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            EditText rollo = new EditText(this);
            rollo.setText(p.getRollno());
            rollo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rollo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(rollo, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);
            CheckBox present = new CheckBox(this);

            present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(present, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

**DatabaseUtility.java**

```
public class DatabaseUtility {

    public static String executeQueryPhp(String phpScript,String queryString) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String line = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "";
            if(queryString!=""){
                url= "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php?"+queryString;  
            }else{
                url = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php"; 
            }
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("Fail 1", "3");

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("Fail 1", "4");

            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            /* finish(); */
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**logcat**

```
    09-22 10:40:42.193: E/Fail 1(8270): 3
09-22 10:40:42.193: E/Fail 1(8270): 4
09-22 10:40:42.193: E/Pass 1(8270): connection success 
09-22 10:40:42.443: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:42.513: D/gralloc_goldfish(8270): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-22 10:40:42.613: E/Position new(8270): Nursery
09-22 10:40:47.386: D/dalvikvm(8270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 186K, 11% free 2958K/3312K, paused 199ms, total 209ms
09-22 10:40:47.592: D/dalvikvm(8270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 10% free 3236K/3588K, paused 32ms, total 35ms
09-22 10:40:47.943: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 135 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:48.112: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:49.053: D/dalvikvm(8270): GREF has increased to 201
09-22 10:40:49.283: E/Position new(8270): Play Group
09-22 10:40:51.913: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 201 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:52.133: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:52.716: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:53.153: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:54.093: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:55.303: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 424 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:40:55.383: D/dalvikvm(8270): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 6% free 3571K/3788K, paused 5ms+33ms, total 324ms
09-22 10:40:55.832: E/Fail 1(8270): 3
09-22 10:40:55.832: E/Fail 1(8270): 4
09-22 10:40:55.832: E/Pass 1(8270): connection success 
09-22 10:40:55.903: I/System.out(8270): [{"first_name":"Md","roll_no":"0"},{"first_name":"Sana","roll_no":"1"},{"first_name":"Tanweer","roll_no":"1"},{"first_name":"zamal","roll_no":"0"}]
09-22 10:41:00.331: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 2731 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:02.053: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:02.273: I/Choreographer(8270): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:05.502: D/AndroidRuntime(8270): Shutting down VM
09-22 10:41:05.502: W/dalvikvm(8270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at com.rushda.attendance.Attend$1.onClick(Attend.java:68)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-22 10:41:05.542: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 10:41:10.093: I/Process(8270): Sending signal. PID: 8270 SIG: 9
09-22 10:41:11.653: D/dalvikvm(8301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 75K, 8% free 2745K/2968K, paused 7ms+22ms, total 84ms
09-22 10:41:11.833: D/dalvikvm(8301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 20K, 6% free 3140K/3308K, paused 6ms+22ms, total 63ms
09-22 10:41:12.094: E/Fail 1(8301): 3
09-22 10:41:12.094: E/Fail 1(8301): 4
09-22 10:41:12.094: E/Pass 1(8301): connection success 
09-22 10:41:12.253: E/Position new(8301): Play Group
09-22 10:41:12.393: E/Position new(8301): Play Group
09-22 10:41:12.433: D/gralloc_goldfish(8301): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-22 10:41:13.973: D/dalvikvm(8301): GREF has increased to 201
09-22 10:41:14.073: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:14.893: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 246 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:15.304: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:15.345: D/dalvikvm(8301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 203K, 10% free 3331K/3680K, paused 5ms+98ms, total 334ms
09-22 10:41:15.693: E/Fail 1(8301): 3
09-22 10:41:15.693: E/Fail 1(8301): 4
09-22 10:41:15.703: E/Pass 1(8301): connection success 
09-22 10:41:15.813: I/System.out(8301): [{"first_name":"Md","roll_no":"0"},{"first_name":"Sana","roll_no":"1"},{"first_name":"Tanweer","roll_no":"1"},{"first_name":"zamal","roll_no":"0"}]
09-22 10:41:17.433: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 984 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:19.063: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:19.873: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 391 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:24.513: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:25.055: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8301): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-22 10:41:25.104: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8301): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-22 10:41:25.212: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:25.632: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 253 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:25.777: D/dalvikvm(8301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 8% free 3576K/3872K, paused 28ms+40ms, total 213ms
09-22 10:41:26.220: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:27.012: W/InputEventReceiver(8301): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
09-22 10:41:27.012: W/InputEventReceiver(8301): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
09-22 10:41:27.012: W/InputEventReceiver(8301): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
09-22 10:41:27.033: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:27.267: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 149 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:27.422: I/Choreographer(8301): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:29.473: D/AndroidRuntime(8301): Shutting down VM
09-22 10:41:29.473: W/dalvikvm(8301): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at com.rushda.attendance.Attend$1.onClick(Attend.java:68)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-22 10:41:29.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 10:41:36.393: I/Process(8301): Sending signal. PID: 8301 SIG: 9
09-22 10:41:37.163: E/Trace(8330): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-22 10:41:37.632: D/dalvikvm(8330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 80K, 8% free 2743K/2972K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 101ms
09-22 10:41:37.823: D/dalvikvm(8330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 19K, 6% free 3140K/3308K, paused 5ms+17ms, total 69ms
09-22 10:41:38.083: E/Fail 1(8330): 3
09-22 10:41:38.083: E/Fail 1(8330): 4
09-22 10:41:38.083: E/Pass 1(8330): connection success 
09-22 10:41:38.203: E/Position new(8330): Play Group
09-22 10:41:38.333: E/Position new(8330): Play Group
09-22 10:41:38.333: I/Choreographer(8330): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 10:41:38.463: D/gralloc_goldfish(8330): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: can you post error from your logcat?

Comment: Please post full logcat. This is just a part of it.

Comment: Hi praveen just now edited my post

Comment: Hi mysticMagic it's giving this error only

Comment: plz post full logcat it is not enough to think of your problem

Comment: you have null pointer Exception Attend.java line 68, it could be `studentname` or `rollno` is Null
`com.rushda.attendance.Attend$1.onClick(Attend.java:68)`

Comment: I posted full logcat

Comment: yazan displaying the table format I used same again I stored into one more variable

Comment: @user1 i have added an answer of what could be the problem

Comment: can any one please help me y data not storing into database

Answer (score 0):

you are missing these:

```
studentname  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentname );
rollno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollno );
```

- assuming studentname and rollno are the ID of the EditTexts in the layout XML file

add them inside `onClick(View v)` just before reading getText() from them

Comment: Hi Yazan If I added two edittext in my xml it showing that studentname and rollno

Comment: but I want displaying data from database edittext id I am not created in my xml

Comment: my question is `name = studentname.getText().toString();` uses an editText object to gettext from, is this object initialized? or it still NULL, the answer is it still NULL because it's declared as `EditText studentname,rollno;` and this will keep it NULL until its assigned using the 2 lines above.

Comment: if you don't want to use XML, you still have to init them using `= new EditText()...` or link them to already existing objects

Comment: if I used Above Two lines inserted means it's showing only name and data not inserted into database

Comment: instead of what? have you init the 2 objects before? where do you intend to get username and rollno values from?